# Rails 3 Windows - won't create a new rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running Win7 and have created Rails 3 apps on this box and have been working with them. Now, when I went to create a new one to try some things - all I get is the "help" ?!? I have:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.3

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25) [i386-mingw32]

$ gem -v
1.6.1

$ rails new somecoolname
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
    -r, [--ruby=PATH]           # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                # Default: c:/ruby/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe
...
```

Any ideas? I have rebooted my Windows 7 box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, plugged away and tried many different things, but could not find any reason for this strangeness. So I decided to try:

```
$ gem update rails
Updating installed gems
Updating rails
Fetching: activesupport-3.0.5.gem (100%)
...
Fetching: rails-3.0.5.gem (100%)
...
```

Now am running rails 3.0.5 and I can create a new Rails 3 app and my old apps still work, Phew! Onward...